# How to convert 24-hour time to 12-hour and send it through Django RestFramework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

[image: This data display timing in 24 hours using angular]

The above image shows 24 hours timing using angular.

---

[image: This data display timing in 12 hours in admin panel]

The above image shows timing in 12 hours in the admin panel.

---

This is the model I want to fetch records sent to **Angular**

```
class Appointment(models.Model):

    service_requested = models.TextField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    appointment_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I tried this but I got a 24-hour time. Is there any way to convert time to 12-hours. and then send it

```
queryset = Appointment.objects.all()
```

Is it the correct way to convert time to 12-hour?

```
from datetime import datetime

queryset = Appointment.objects.all().annotate( 

           date_time = datetime.strptime('appointment_date_time','%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')

           ).values('service_requested','customer','date_time')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, see this:

```
<td>{{book.appointment_date_time| date:'medium'}}</td>
```

In html file i just add template filter.

For more detail about the date format see this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date